# XCode not finding crash logs

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash, logging, xcode-organizer

I have a problem with `XCode organiser`, which is not showing any new iPhone app crash log anymore.

I checked in `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice`, the files have not been copied there either. Nor are they even if i synchronize the mobile with iTunes.

I reproduce the problem with 2 devices (iphone and ipod), however if I connect them on other computers, the logs are visible. So it seems the problem is with this **XCode/Mac OS**.

Any ideas ? Has anyone come across the same problem ?

Thanks,

Comment: had this problem once, restarted XCode after I connected by iPhone and there where the crash logs.

Comment: hum, but no luck; I even restarted the mac, as well as the devices, and the crash logs are still not shown.

Comment: Have you syced the device with your computer through Itunes? X code doesn't show crash logs until you sync the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, I found it. I had to reinstall iTunes and the "Mobile Device Service", as shown [in here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1747?viewlocale=en_US), and now crash logs are visible again.

Edit: as the page fell, here are the steps from the [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20141120170308/http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201628) page. Note that those steps worked on Mac Os X 10.6, but may be different on current versions.

> If the issue persists, follow these steps to remove and reinstall the Apple Mobile Device Service on Mac OS X. You'll need to authenticate with an administrator account and password to complete these steps.
>
> 1. Disconnect your device from your Mac.
> 2. In the Finder, locate iTunes in the Applications folder and drag it to the Trash.
> 3. Move the iTunes icon to the Trash.
> 4. Choose **Go** > **Go to Folder**.
> 5. Enter `/System/Library/Extensions` and click Go.
> 6. Locate the file
>      `AppleMobileDevice.text`
>      and drag it to the Trash.
> 7. Choose **Go** > **Go to Folder**.
> 8. Enter
>      `/Library/Receipts/`
>      and click Go.
> 9. Locate the file
>      `AppleMobileDeviceSupport.pkg`
>      and drag it to the Trash. If prompted, authenticate with the administrator password.
>
> Note: This file may not be present in Mac OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard; skip to the next step if this is the case.
>
> 10. Restart the computer.
> 11. Choose Finder > Empty Trash and restart the computer.
> 12. Download and install the current version of iTunes.
> 13. Connect your device to the Mac again and open iTunes

Comment: I tried to do as mentioned in the link, but seems it's not for OS X 10.8. Any idea how to reinstall iTunes and Mobile Device Service in OS X 10.8.2/3

Comment: ...and this is why we ask people to include relevant parts of the link in their answer. Downvoting.

Comment: "We" ask people ? This answer was posted before you registered to the site

Answer (score 6):

New device / crash logs will only appear when the iPhone is sync with the computer via iTunes.

Hopefully this will help others.